# Me muestra un error con el Manifest

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Tengo este error en android studio

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>   Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.0-alpha1) from [com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1] AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-38     is also present at [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-31 value=(25.3.1).    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:22:5-24:41 to override.

**Este es mi gradle app**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Esto yo se lo agregue**

```
noinspection GradleCompatible
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
```

Al `manifest` no le he cambiado nada, espero me puedan decir como solucionarlo y cual es la lógica para no tener este problema en el futuro. Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Algunas bibliotecas dependen de la versión ***"X o posterior"*** (ten cuidado con el uso de añadir .x ya que puede producir problemas con tu código a medida de actualizaciones) de las bibliotecas de soporte de Android, por lo que la resolución de dependencia del `Gradle` toma lo que sea más nuevo, ignorando que realmente tiene una versión precisa especificada en su `dependencies`

Todas las bibliotecas de soporte deben tener la misma versión y la versión principal tenga que coincidir con la versión de compilación del SDK.

Pon esto al final de tu módulo de aplicación `build.gradle` :

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '25.3.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

"Con esto puedes forzar a utilizar una versión especifica". Por supuesto, reemplace la versión que esté usando.

Para mas informacion y si tienes dudas, revisa la [documentación](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:blacklisting_version). del método bien documentado.

Answer (score -1):

En este caso estas definiendo versiones distintas de las libraries android lo cual no es recomendable, te sugiero usar las mismas versiones.

En cuanto al problema principal se debe a que estas definiendo la dependencia:

> `'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'`

Al especificar el signo "+" en realidad esta tomando la library

> com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1

Esta library del RecyclerView es una version antigua, de hecho me parece fue la primera version "alpha".

**Para solucionar el problema define versiones similares de tus libraries de soporte** por ejemplo si estas definiendo un `targetSdkVersion 25`, define:

```
'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
```